# How can I split a theano tensor unequally and sum its parts?

Tags: split, sum, theano

I have a theano tensor and I would like to split it into subtensors according to a predefined index list and then sum the subtensors.

As an example:
If I have a vector [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], I want to split it with respect to the index list [1,4,6],(split after the first element, split after the fourth element, split after the 6th element. This should give me [[1], [2,3,4], [5,6], [7]].) The output should be the sum of the individual splits, that is  [[1], [9], [11], [7]].

The code in python would look like

```
def f(a, idx):
    splitList = np.split(a, idx)
    for i in range(len(splitList)):
        splitList[i] = sum(splitList[i])
    return splitList

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
idx = [1,4,6]

outcome = f(a,idx)

# outcome is [1, 9, 11, 7]
```

I know there is a split function as well in theano, but I don't understand its usage.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you already tried, and clarify what are your problems / where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you please specify more clearly what is your desired output.

Comment: I have edited question to make it more clear. Thank you!